# How to use a relative path in sqlcmd script

Tags: sql-server

Can someone tell me how to swap this absolute path with a relative one for my sqlcmd upgrade script?

```
-- how can I get rid of the following absolute path variable from my script?
:SETVAR ScriptDir "C:\absolutePath\"  

:SETVAR DeployLog "upgradeDb.out.log"
:SETVAR ErrorLog "upgradeDb.err.log"
:Error $(ScriptDir)$(ErrorLog)
:OUT $(ScriptDir)$(DeployLog)

:ON ERROR EXIT
print ' run scripts a and b'
:r $(ScriptDir)"a.sql"
:r $(ScriptDir)"b.sql"

PRINT 'finished'
GO

:EXIT 
print 'problem...'
GO
```

Originally posted (in the wrong place) here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318033/how-to-use-a-relative-path-in-sqlcmd-script

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking how to edit the script file? Do you not know what the path is? Something else?

Comment: How are you executing this script? Command line via SQLCMD.EXE or in SSMS using SQLCMD mode?

Comment: the script's being run in SSMS in sqlcmd mode. If I don't set the path explicitly the cwd turns out to be the folder that SSMS is in IIRC. These scripts go out to a customer and then I don't know where they're being run from and I'm having to tell the customer to manually edit them before running them in SSMS. It seems like the kind of thing I shouldn't have to be doing. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you want a relative path, just use relative path notation.
`:SETVAR ScriptDir "../../"`

That will set your ScriptDir to two directories higher than wherever you invoked `sqlcmd` from.

or 
`:SETVAR ScriptDir "moo/oink/bah/"`

That will look for scripts in the `moo/oink/bah` subdirectory of wherever you invoked `sqlcmd` from.

Comment: I've tried this and although you'd think it would work it doesn't. CWD turns out to be location of SSMS.exe and not the master script's.

Comment: I usually launch sqlcmd.exe from PowerShell, in which case the relative paths work fine.